# How to add trial to stripe checkout using ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, stripe-payments

What is that syntax for adding a trial to asp core 3.1 using stripe checkout? I'm trying to assign TrialPeriodDays to SubscriptionData for a 7 day free trial.

```
// Checkout Session
var options = new SessionCreateOptions
                  {
                      LineItems = new List<SessionLineItemOptions>
                                  {
                                      new SessionLineItemOptions
                                          {
                                              Price = "price_1KJSMXC...",
                                              Quantity = 1,
                                          },
                                  },
                      // I believe I need to assign the trial to SubscriptionData below
                      SubscriptionData = { },           
                      Mode = "subscription",

                      SuccessUrl = "https://example.com/Success",
                      CancelUrl = "https://example.com/Cancel",
                  };
```

Comment: I couldn't see the code you created the service: `var service = new SessionService();
service.Create(options);`

Comment: If you are looking for a guide that walks you through how to get one-time payments and sell fixed-price subscriptions and provides an example of a well-working integration with Stripe, look at the demo --> https://techtolia.com/Stripe/New/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
...
SubscriptionData = new Stripe.Checkout.SessionSubscriptionDataOptions
{
  TrialPeriodDays = 7
},
Mode = "subscription",
....
```

Comment: awesome works perfectly, they also changed the subscribe button to start trial as a nice touch